# Local state working properly but when I try the same with Redux it doesn't work

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, redux

On this component I am rendering 2 routes. With local state it works perfect but I am trying to achieve the same with Redux but I don't have an idea about how to send the signal to redux in order to change the `index` part of this piece of state.

This is how it was working before:

```
class MyComp extends Component {
  state = {
    index: 0,
    routes: [
      { key: 'first', title: 'Drop-Off' },
      { key: 'second', title: 'Pick up' },
    ],
  };

  handleIndexChange = indexParam => {
    const { navigation } = this.props;

    this.setState({ index: indexParam });

    if (indexParam) navigation.navigate('App2');
    else navigation.navigate('App');
  };
}
```

And this in the render method:

```
  render() {
    return (
      <TabView
        navigationState={this.state}
        onIndexChange={this.handleIndexChange}
      />
    );
  }
```

That code above was working as expected. Now I need the same but with Redux so I may stop using local state.
Action:

```
import ActionTypes from '../constants/ActionTypes';

export const indexRouteAction = index => ({
  type: ActionTypes.INDEX_ROUTE,
  payload: {
    index,
  },
});

export default indexRouteAction;
```

Reducer:

```
import createReducer from '../../../redux/createReducer';
import ActionTypes from '../constants/ActionTypes';

const initialState = {
  navigation: {
    index: 0,
    routes: [
      { key: 'first', title: 'Drop-Off' },
      { key: 'second', title: 'Pick up' },
    ],
  },
};

const handlers = {
  [ActionTypes.INDEX_ROUTE](state, action) {
    return {
      ...state,
      index: action.payload.index,
    };
  },
};

export default createReducer(initialState, handlers);
```

So now what can I do to handle that data from the component? 
I have something like this:
Render method:

```
  render() {
    const { navigationStore } = this.props;
    return (
      <TabView
        navigationState={navigationStore}
        onIndexChange={this.handleIndexChange}
      />
    );
  }
```

And I am calling the store like this:

```
export default compose(
  connect(
    store => ({
      navigationStore: store.homeScreen.navigation,
    }),
    dispatch => ({
      indexRouteActionHandler: data => {
        dispatch(indexRouteAction(data));
      },
    }),
  ),
)(withNavigation(TopTabView));
```

And this is the function where I change the index on an onClick function:

```
  handleIndexChange = indexParam => {
    // BEFORE WITH STATE THIS FUNCTION WORKED WITH SETSTATE
    // NOW I HAVE TO MAKE IT WORK WITH REDUX STATE
    // this.setState({ index: indexParam });
    const { indexRouteActionHandler, navigation } = this.props;
    indexRouteActionHandler(indexParam);
    if (indexParam) navigation.navigate('App2');
    else navigation.navigate('App');
  };
```

Wo what am I missing?

**UPDATE:**

Something I noticed is that this is what I see on Redux DevTools:

```
{
  homeScreen: {
    navigation: {
      index: 0,
      routes: [
        {
          key: 'first',
          title: 'Drop-Off',
          routeName: 'DropOffHome'
        },
        {
          key: 'second',
          title: 'Pick up',
          routeName: 'PickupHome'
        }
      ]
    },
    index: 0
  }
}
```

I see there are 2 indexes and the one changing its state is the index outside of navigation: `navigation: {...}, index: 0` I need to get the one inside of navigation: `navigation: {index: 0, routes: [...]}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't update the state correctly in redux store. The index value is inside `navigation` and hence you need to update it like

```
const handlers = {
  [ActionTypes.INDEX_ROUTE](state, action) {
    return {
      ...state,
      navigation: {
         ...state.navigation,
         index: action.payload.index,
      }
    };
  },
};
```